# How can I set my password for my database user once?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I have started a new project using docker-compose however my migrations and database queries are falling with the error `Access denied for user 'data-jobs'@'172.18.0.3' (using password: YES)`

I have 2 config files. `.env` for my laravel configuration and `.db.env` for my database environment variables. I got this error because I had changed the value in the .env file but not in the .db.env file.

My question is this:

How can I use can I pass `MYSQL_PASSWORD` and `DB_PASSWORD` to Laravel and MariaDB using only one config key to prevent me making this mistake again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your env variables names are wrong, the Docker mysql image uses different keys.

```
MYSQL_USER
MYSQL_DATABASE
....
```

https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

(MariaDB as a drop-in replacement uses the same keys.)

If you want to use your custom keys, you need to map them in the docker-compose.yml:

```
db-data-jobs:
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: db-data-jobs
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    env_file:
      - .db.env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    networks:
      - app-net
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Make sure you don't twist the names of your files: `.env` and `.db.env`.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering you made me find the fault which was that my password in `.db.env` didn't match what was in the `.env` file. However .db.env is another file in my directory specifically for the mysql environment keys. So that they are not included in version control and can have different permissions. I use `0660`.

Comment: I've now updated my question to see if we can find a way to prevent a repeat of this mistake.

Comment: @Ben you have changed your question completely. But your question is still answered: Use mapping and/or multiple .env files as described in https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: When I put a `-` before the environment variable in the compose file I got an error that it wasn't a string. Removing the `-` fixed the error and the service is working perfectly.

Comment: @Ben ah you are right, the syntax is not `- MYSQL_USER: ...` but `- MYSQL_USER=...`! Glad it worked for you!